# MSAL-Angular routing

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL in my angular project and most of it is working fine. The problem is with my routing. It is not working or i am not doing it right. When i logout or path is empty it doesn't go to login page also if i put the login route then it ask for login credential twice. First credential take me from login route(https://app.zoomtalktext.com/login) to empty route(https://app.zoomtalktext.com/login) and then to my homepage.My approach work if i don't use MSAL guard and use my own written Auth guard
Following is my routing code -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './helpers/auth.guard';
import { MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./home-layout/home-layout.module').then(m => m.HomeLayoutModule),canActivate: [MsalGuard] },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule) }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: What routing approach are you following ?

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha Lazy loading routes in angular. If authenticated it load home-layout routes which takes user to home page by for empty routes if not authenticated it goes to login route.

Comment: Put your exact routes first as it checks for routes sequentially.

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha I want to load my modules on demand thats why i used lazy loading  routing approach. My approach work if i don't use msal guard and use my own written auth guard

Comment: It's difficult to say just looking at the routes. Can you make a codesandbox ?

Comment: 'When i logout or path is empty it doesn't go to login page' - 
This happens because I think it considers the empty path to load your home layout as it's written before login path.

Comment: @ChandradeeptaLaha Yea but if you are not authenticated it should go the next path which is login. Also, If i do not use MSAL guard and use my own guard this approach work fine.

Comment: Is there any way to look at the code?