# How to redirect to an Angular custom made Login page if the user is not logged in

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, angular-router-guards, angular-pagination

In my current case I have an Angular application with Azure AD and MSAL v2 implementation. What I want to achieve is when the user is not logged in redirecting them to the custom made Login page with a simple **Login (click)="login()"** button. I've followed [this project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-login-hide-navbar-layout) to get where I am now but unfortunately after navigating to ' / ' path of localhost:4200 I am getting redirected straight to the Microsoft login page instead of ' */login* '. Am I missing something here? Here is my *routing module*:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [MsalGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', component: WelcomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'map-requests', component: MapRequestsComponent},
      { path: 'map-requests/map-request/details', component: MaprequestDetailComponent }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Found similar question on stack: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341553/msal-angular-routing)

Comment: It may just be I've never tried it before, but it looks like your route array has two paths to ' '.   Your auth guard looks to be routing correctly to '/login' so I'm just wondering why two paths going to ' '.  Also, which component is the microsoft login page?

Comment: Can you show MsalGuard

Comment: There’s no Microsoft login component as such. Just a standard MSAL implementation from this sample code from Microsoft itself: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-angular-spa/tree/main/src/app
The only difference is that the app.component.ts code is implemented in my HomeLayoutComponent.

Comment: @Tejeshree MsalGuard is an standard implementation from the following library: '@azure/msal-angular'

Comment: I will check the documentation, meanwhile, can you see any verbose logs? It seems that MsalGuard is returning true & so it's taking that route?

Comment: Yeah it goes straight to the first route, which is HomLayoutComponent. No other errors/logs, beside token acquire success logging.

Comment: Hi all, is there any solution ? I have same issue and I could not figure out solution yet

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [post](https://njkhanh.com/redirect-to-a-custom-login-page-when-securing-your-angular-app-with-msal-p5f3137323235) I found the solution, the solution is to add a second guard which will check if a user is logged in or not, this is how the auth guard looks like.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { MsalBroadcastService, MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { InteractionStatus } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CanActivateGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private msalService: MsalService,
        private router: Router,
        private msalBroadcastService: MsalBroadcastService) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
        return this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$
            .pipe(
                filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
                switchMap(() => {
                    if (this.msalService.instance.getAllAccounts().length > 0) {
                        return of(true);
                    }

                    this.router.navigate( ['/auth/login'] );
                    return of(false);
                }),
            );
        }
}
```

Note: Depending on your rxjs version, you may need to import operators from rxjs library like this

```
import { Observable, of, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, the above solution of using 
return this.msalBroadcastService.inProgress$ 
didnt work for me. I think the reason is canActivate doesnt return until the observable returns

Comment: For me this works! but after logging in its bring me to login page for a second then redirect to home page.